# Is there a way to translate this TypeScript piece to JavaScript in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, translate

I need to use this in my .js file but I have no idea how to make it javascript. Here's the function:

```
async function readLines(filename: string, processLine: (line: string) => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        lineReader.eachLine(filename, (line, last, callback) => {
            if (!callback) throw new Error('panic');
            processLine(line)
            .then(() => last ? resolve() : callback())
            .catch(reject);
        });
    });
}
```

Now here's how I call it:

```
await readLines(filename, async (line) => {
await delay(1000)
some_other_func(line);
});
```

Comment: `async function readLines(filename, processLine) {`  -- `await readLines('path/to/file', async (line) => {...})`

Comment: Okay I don't think that will work for my code, I edited the post with the entire function

Comment: Compile it with TypeScript. Or copy/paste it into [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and look at the JS tab.

Comment: All TypeScript by definition can be translated to JavaScript. If it cannot be expressed in JavaScript, it cannot go into the TypeScript language, as TypeScript's entire purpose is to transpile to JavaScript. To ask an on-topic question here, you need to ask something specific about the process of translation, and if you've found an answer, that answer has to be posted below as an answer, not edited into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the parameter `processLine` type and the return value type.

```js
async function readLines(filename, processLine) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        lineReader.eachLine(filename, (line, last, callback) => {
            if (!callback) throw new Error('panic');
            processLine(line)
            .then(() => last ? resolve() : callback())
            .catch(reject);
        });
    });
}
```